# Bootstrap scrollbar slipped behind content

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

[image: Scrollbar hidden behind content?!]

I am working on a webpage using Bootstrap 4 and after fixing the appearance of a horizontal scrollbar on mobile devices by adding overflow-x:hidden to the html tag I noticed that the main y scrollbar looked weird and was not clickable most of the time anymore (normally it can be pulled with the left mouse button, but it does not react to clicks now. It does, however, register clicks on content that is behind the scrollbar!).

It has definitely not been like this for long, but I have not the faintest idea what caused this change since I did not touch any z-index or scrollbar settings...

I am using Chrome and it should display the standard, unstyled scrollbar, which does not look like this.
Can anyone tell me what happened and how to fix it?!

Edit:
Since it happens across all pages equally the error should be somewhere in the main template and since most of that gets overwritten it is most probably in the header. Maybe someone can spot the mistake:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
  <head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'bilder/icons/019-rocket.svg' %}">

    <title>Online-Nachhilfe</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin:0;padding:0;
      background-image: url({% static 'bilder/Rastergrafik.png' %});
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      overflow-x: hidden !important;
      position:relative;
      z-index:0;
      min-height: 101vh;
      text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    {% block head %}
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I can't exactly post hundreds of lines of code from the entire project, can I? Unfortunately, I don't know remotely what I changed to cause this and I have been working all over the site today... BUT I know I did not adjust anything concerning scrollbars or z-index. Maybe it is a common problem? I can't find anything similar though... I hoped someone could immediately tell what happened from the scrollbar design in the image.

Comment: I dont give you any information from showing one image, you can upload your UI code into codepen, stackblitz, jsfiddle etc.

Comment: I just edited my post to contain the template header that is most likely to contain the mistake, but thank you for your advice. It should be in there somewhere, since it would not transfer to all of the other pages otherwise and I doubt it is the standard bootstrap code's fault

Comment: This is not valid in SO but from your CSS, I can bet, Horizontal scrollbar come from `min-height` property

Comment: I did have problems with horizontal scrollbars on mobile initially which is why I included the overflow hidden on the main HTML tag, but neither  removing that or the min-height:101vh; in the body style does anything to address this vertical scrollbar problem...

Comment: I think the problem is in code but I can't find it, you must need to provide code

Comment: the scrollbar you see here is not a normal desktop scrollbar, so i guess you have a script included or you made the screenshot in mobile settings, which makes it no visible problem. So without more code....

Comment: @Rmaxx I think you're right about that. By chance, I entered the site from a new, clean tab and got a perfectly normal scrollbar again. So I can confidently say it is definitely not a code Problem, but a tab or browser settings problem. It does seem to be the mobile scrollbar, yet I am not in inspector or doing anything special, maybe it is a Chrome feature caused by a certain hotkey combo?! No idea, but I will close this thread since it is not the code causing the issue. Thanks a lot for your time, both of you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out not to be a code problem after all and the browser seemingly just decided to show me the mobile scrollbar version instead of the normal one for no apparent reason. It can be fixed by entering the site from a clean tab or deleting browser cache and restarting chrome. The code seems to be working perfectly 100%!